# How to make OS to mount USB as user

Tags: debian, mount, usb, kde

In debian jessie KDE, when I plug USB stick and click it in dolphin (it mounted automatically), stick mounted as root, while I am using standard user account. So I need to get superuser to manipulate files on the USB or remount with **-o uid=1000,gid=100**

So, I need to make USB sticks to be mounted as user by default. How?

Comment: Mounting as you should be the default. Do you know of anything unusual about your installation? Did you install jessie originally or did you upgrade to it? In environments other than KDE (e.g. Gnome, LXDE, XFCE), are USB sticks mounted automatically, and as what user?

Comment: I've installed jessie originally, doesn't try on other DE. When I done working with flash in GParted it can mounted as user, or cannot. I have this trouble with all my jessie installations on this computer and other/